# If two lists have same elements, sum other element of these lists

Tags: python, list

I cannot find a solution for a problem like this one:

```
list1 = [['mark', 27],['tom',13],['mark',12],['mark', 12]]

listR = []

if listR[0][0] == list1[0][0]:
    listR[0][1] += list1[0][1]
    list1.pop(0)
else:
    listR.append(list1.pop(0))
```

I would like to iterate over the first list so that it keeps on adding all items to `listR`.

But I would like to restrict that if first element of sub-list (e.g. `list1[1][0]`) is the same as existing one in sub-list of `listR` (e.g. `list1[3][0]`, then sub-list is not going to be copied to `listR`, but score (e.g. `list1[2][1]`) that is in that sub-list is going to be added to the existing sub-list in `listR`.

@edit

Please suggest a solution using only lists.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want the result to be `listR = [['mark', 51], ['tom', 13]]`?

Comment: Ok, so it's like an association list. What you probably need to do is accumulate (i.e. sum) the values occurring under common names (which suggests a dict). Once you have such a dict, you can convert it back to an association list using a list comprehension.

Comment: yes. that is the result I want to achieve

Comment: I was trying to use dict before but I was struggling. Can I do it based on indexes of the sub-arrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum values of tuples stored as key value pair in list by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342908/sum-values-of-tuples-stored-as-key-value-pair-in-list-by-key)

Comment: @kksi yes you can, but as you have seen it is more complicated and difficult, while using a dictionary is easy

Comment: Also by using `pop` you made it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Can anybody suggest a solution using only lists?

Comment: @kkski I've updated my answer with a straightforward list-based implementation. However, I highly recommend just using the right tool for the job here.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those problems where choosing a better data structure makes the problem solve itself. You can use a defaultdict to keep the score and simplify the code like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

scores = [['mark', 27], ['tom',13], ['mark',12], ['mark', 12]]
totalscores = defaultdict(int)

for name, score in scores:
    totalscores[name] += score
```

`totalscores` is now

```
defaultdict(int, {'mark': 51, 'tom': 13})
```

You could also use pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['name', 'score'])
df.groupby('name').sum()
```

If you absolutely must use lists, the logic is easier if you traverse the elements in sorted order:

```py
lastname = None
totalscores = []
total = 0

for name, score in sorted(scores):
    if lastname is not None and name != lastname:
        totalscores.append([lastname, total])
        total = 0
    total += score
    lastname = name

if lastname is not None:
    totalscores.append([lastnamename, total])
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP's suggestion to use only lists, you can directly manipulate `listR` as if it were an association list. For that you need a way to locate a key:

```
def find_by_name(name, lst, ind=0):
    if len(lst) == 0:      
        return None
    elif lst[0][0] == name:                                                          
        return ind   
    else:                        
        return find_by_name(name, lst[1:], ind+1)
```

which you can then use as follows:

```
for [name, score] in list1:
    i = find_by_name(name, listR)
    if i is not None:
        listR[i][1]+= score
    else:
        listR.append([name, score])
```